# UICollectionView - custom calendar swipe through month / years

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, calendar, swipe

I'm programming a simple custom calendar. I'm using a `collectionView` with the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

At the moment I have a `collectionView` holding 12 cells. Each cell is maximized to the size of the `collectionView` width and height, every cell contains and owns `collectionView` and is loading a specific month.

As an example cell 1 is holding January, cell 2 is holding February and they displaying these months with and own `collectionView`.

All is working fine and smooth, but I need to change the years. So if the user goes to the last cell (December) as an example, he should continuously scroll while the year is changing.

Or if the user is going backward and wants to go in the past, it should scroll continuously while changing the year from 2020 to 2019. Hopefully, I explained it understandable.

[My calendar right now (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNc1M.gif)

Comment: consider adding some code

Comment: super basic I will try to modify the array of months, adding next/previous year and change the UI based on what month are you displaying

Comment: Do you mean showing a next/previous button? This would be easy, but it is not what iam searching for.

Comment: when you are displaying December you add the next 12 month (next year) to the array of months and reload collectionview, that will allow you to continue swipe after december in Jan, and when you are displaying January of the of the current year you add previous 12 months(previous year). you get the point. you mighr want to make a bit of clean up not to leave to many months in the array you feed to the collectionVIew.

Comment: It works forward, but backwards its not working continously, its lagging if i add new objects to the beginning. And if i delete objects from the beginning it is also lagging...